# How can I approximate walking physics via simpler sliding physics?

Tags: physics

I am modeling walking insects.  I implement them as cuboids and use forces (including friction and drag), to control motion.  However, the movement characteristics of this 'sliding box' physics don't match those due to a legged creature.

For example, legged creatures near-instantly accelerate to their top speed; whereas applying a force to a box takes time to accelerate it.

The applied force can be increased along with the counteracting drag, giving much quicker acceleration (via force) to a max speed (via drag).  However, this also means the force that creatures can exert when pushing on other objects is increased.

Does anyone know of any techniques using a physics engine to cheaply model walking creatures?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**High movement impulse, with high drag, will work perfectly.** For collisions, you **don't** use the force that is being applied for movement in the collision calculation, you use the resulting speed, mass, elasticity, etc.

Comment: Come to think of it, that's actually how real physics work.